# ObjectMapper does not map internal Object value of a Object

Tags: java, java-8, objectmapper, modelmapper

There is a `User` object like this:

```java
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String family;
    private Book book;
    // With its own setter & getter methods
}
```

And the following code is used to convert from `LinkedHashMap` value to `User` object:

```java
LinkedHashMap result = linkedHashMap.get("principal");
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
User user = objectMapper.convertValue(result, User.class);
```

But after `objectMapper.convertValue`, the `Book` object of `User` is `null` while the `LinkedHashMap result` has the book object value.

How do I fix my problem?

**Edit**:
It is necessary to mention the `Book` object has its own Object too, and I want to map the Object of Book too.

The `LinkedHashMap` value is [here](https://ufile.io/hfrg35qj)

Comment: Does the book object and its respective getters have the proper access modifiers? Also it is hard to tell why this happens without seeing what the LinkedHashMap actually contains

Comment: can you share the contents of result and class of `Book` too ?

Comment: What's your JSON document like?

Comment: I put the image of LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by changing from ObjectMapper to ModelMapper like:

```
ModelMapper.map(result, User.class);
```